# How to prove that Quaternion's algebra over isomorphic to Mat2(Z

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, quaternions

My ideas: I tried to build an explicit isomorphism, but as I think it is only possible when p = 1 (mod 4), and for p = 1 (mod 4) it get it.
In my second attempt, I tried to look at them as vector spaces of the same dimension.

Comment: How is the quaternion algebra defined exactly? I don't get your notation.

Comment: $i^2 = j^2  = k^2 = -1, ij = k ..., $ q = a +bi + cj + dk, where a,b,c,d $\in$ Zp

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214078/when-does-a-quaternion-algebra-isomorphic-to-m-2f).

Comment: Yes, they are surely isomorphic as vector spaces. But it feels like it's rather claimed to be an isomorphism of algebras, including multiplication.

Comment: Please do not crosspost: https://mathoverflow.net/q/423172/6518

Answer (score 2):

Find $a,b\in \Bbb{F}_p$ such that $a^2+b^2=-1$ then let $i=\pmatrix{a&b\\b&-a},j=
\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$

so that $k=ij=\pmatrix{-b&a\\a&b}$ and indeed $k=-ji, i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$

If $p\ne 2$ then it will be 4-dimensional so it will span the whole of $M_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$